# Refrescar div cada x segundos

Tags: javascript, div

tengo un div y dentro del mismo llamo a un metodo de una clase en PHP que muestra cierta información de la base de datos.

Algo tal que así

```
<div id="Ejemplo">
  <?php $ejemplo = new ClaseYoQueSe(); echo $ejemplo->Mostrar_dato(); ?>
</div>
```

La idea es, que ese div se pueda actualizar cada X tiempo sin necesidad de que el usuario necesite hacer relogeo de la página entera.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Y por curiosidad, ¿Existe alguna forma de actualizar unicamente cuándo el valor cambie, para así evitar actualizar de forma innecesaria? Imagino que no, porque de alguna forma has de saber si el dato ha cambiado, e igualmente tendrías que evaluarlo cada X tiempo.

Comment: te recomiendo esto : http://lineadecodigo.com/javascript/ejecutar-cada-x-segundos-en-javascript/

Comment: Tendrias que hacerlo con Ajax y luego crear un intervalo de tiempo con setInterval()

Comment: sobre tu inquietud de si puedes saber si el valor a cambiado si claro, usa web storage de html5 y de esa manera haces una validacion previa al call de tu recarga de div, te dejo una URL informativa, saludos: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Tienes varias opciones (p.e. ajax o websockets). Hay algunas preguntas en el sitio sobre este tema, busca sobre ajax o websockets y encontrarás solución a lo que buscas.

Answer (score 3):

Podés usar [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) de jQuery para hacer una petición cada cierta cantidad de tiempo con `setInterval()`, por ejemplo:

#### javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // intervalo
  setInterval(function() {
    // petición ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: 'claseYoQueSe.php',
      success: function(data) {
        // reemplazo el texto que va dentro de #Ejemplo
        $('#Ejemplo').text(data);
      }
    });
  }, 10000); // cada 10 segundos, el valor es en milisegundos
});
```

#### PHP (archivo `claseYoQueSe.php`)

```
<?php
  $ejemplo = new ClaseYoQueSe(); echo $ejemplo->Mostrar_dato();
  // formateo a json para javascript
  json_encode($ejemplo);
?>
```